# How do I use <uint64_t> in an array

Tags: c++, uint64

i'm pretty new to C++ and am trying to make an array in which every element is of a specific bit-size. I've tried doing this:
`Sequence<uint64_t>;`
In which Sequence would be the array name and every element would have a size of 64 bits. However get the following error: "error: ‘Sequence’ does not name a type"
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think that defining an array of `uint64_t` works any different from defining any other array? If you don't know how to declare arrays at all, then please start learning the language from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). This is not a tutorial site.

Comment: `uint64_t array_name[array_size];`? Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: What's a `Sequence`? The error is telling you that there's no such thing...

Comment: @ChrisMM "_In which Sequence would be the array name_". They seem to just not know how syntax for variable declarations works at all.

Comment: `vector<uint64_t> Sequence;` should solve the issue

Comment: @user17732522, you're right, missed that part.

Comment: In the code shown in the question, neither `Sequence` nor `uint64_t` is defined. So it's not the least bit surprising that it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) are the recomended array containers in C++.

You can use `std::vector` if you need a dynamic size array, e.g.:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
std::vector<uint64_t> v;
```

And use `std::array` for a fixed size array, e.g.:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
std::array<uint64_t, 10> a;
```

You can see in the links above how to use these containers.

Comment: You forgot the include for uint64_t

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow thanks. MSVC didn't complain so I forgot it. Added now.